# Slow simple SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a small/big problem with a simple select query on SQL Server.

I have a table called Waypoints with the following columns

```
Id - bigint PK
Location - nvarchar(50)
Description - nvarchar(100),
RouteId - bigint,
Order - int,
isStop - bit
```

And my query is:

```
select * from Waypoints;
```

I already have an index in the RouteId column but performance is still slow, this being 7 - 9s for 302,592 rows.

Do you have any idea for optimization?

[image: Execution Plan Here]

Comment: how many rows altogether?

Comment: That table hast 302,592 rows

Comment: index is only useful if you select up to about 10% of table data. Otherwise full table scan is better

Comment: Does the performance increase if you do a `select * from Waypoints order by Id`?

Comment: @robbpriestley it actually did, it's a small difference but it did improved it, thanks

Comment: Yeah good, that's because of what Ken said above, ordering invokes the index. So it's seeming like you may need to live with it as such. All those `bigint`s are taxing the CPU I suppose. Maybe you could add more RAM and/or CPU cores?

Comment: Am I missing something?  The question should include the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff select * from Waypoints;

Comment: @MiguelMorgado, retrieving all columns and rows from a table will be limited by your network speed and client processing time.

Comment: Indexing a bit column will result in two parts, true and false. If the data is split 50/50 the gain will be 'some'.

Answer (score 0):

You can put filter on it on indexed column.

If you want to get all data maybe you can try this:

```
select * from Waypoints order by Id
```

And if it is still slow there is one thing left , that is your network speed and client processing time